# Upgrading Blazor project to Net Core 6 breaks Websocket

Tags: websocket, blazor, .net-6.0

I've had a Blazor project built in Net Core 5, but wanted to test new functionality of Net Core 6 previews. After upgrading the framework, I tried to build the app but got greeted by a single error: "WebSocket is not in the OPEN state". I've tried to use some solutions I've found to no avail. Not even the full release has helped me.

[Errors that appear when app is compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iskXs.png)

Comment: If what you claim were true, SignalR and by extension Blazor Server wouldn't work at all. A lot of people would have noticed. Post code that actually reproduces your problem with the expected behavior, the actual result and actual *complete* errors or exceptions. If you have an exception post the complete text, not just the message part

Comment: Suggest you create a new Blazor Server project using .NET 6 and then compare the various files with yours to see what might be different.